# C++ pointer Undefined reference

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int bsearch(int arr[], int l,int h, int x);
int check(int arr[],int k);
int main()
{
    int n,m,arr_str=0;
    cin >> n;
    int arr_s[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin >> arr_s[i];
    cin >> m;
    int arr_q[m];
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        cin >> arr_q[j];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        arr_str = arr_s[i];
        if(check(arr_q,m))
            cout << arr_s[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
int bsearch(int arr[], int l,int h, int x)
{
    if(h>=l)
    {
        int mid = l +  (h-l)/2;
        if(arr[mid] == x)
            return 1;
        else if(arr[mid]>x)
            bsearch(arr,l,mid-1,x);

        return bsearch(arr,mid+1,h,x);
    }
    else
        return -1;
}

int check(int arr[],int l, int m)
{
    if(bsearch(arr,0,m,l))
        return 0;
    else 
        return 1;
}
```

I have been receiving the following errors

undefined reference to check(*int, int)
 Id returned 1 exit status

In spite the fact that I have added three parameters in the check function and given the same in the main() code it showing error 
How is an array value passed in such cases

Comment: `int n; int arr_s[n];` is not legal C++ because `n` is not a compile time constant (it would be legal C though). Some C++ compilers allow it, your obviously does, but that doesn't mean it's legal.

Comment: In that case, should I add like this
int *arr_s = new int[n];

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of check has three parameters

```
int check(int arr[],int l, int m)
```

you call it in main with two parameters

```
if(check(arr_q,m))
```

and you prototype (aka declare) it with two

```
int check(int arr[],int k);
```

Make you mind up whether you want two or three parameters and this problem will be fixed.

Comment: Also use bool not int  for functions that  are meant to be true or false. It looks like bsearch is meant to be boolean but will only ever return 1 or -1 which are both non-zero so will always be true when used in check() which will always return 0.

Comment: The code probably has many other problems, for instance there is a missing return here `else if(arr[mid]>x)
            bsearch(arr,l,mid-1,x);`. Should be `else if(arr[mid]>x)
            return bsearch(arr,l,mid-1,x);` of course.

Answer (score 0):

Just before the main function, you defined the Check function as `int check(int arr[],int k);`.

Update the definition and everything is just okay.

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition and function declaration are different. While you initially declare the `check()` function to have two parameters i.e. a pointer and an integer

```
int check(int arr[],int k);
```

You define the function however with 3 parameters

```
int check(int arr[],int l, int m)
```

Update the declaration to be

```
int check(int arr[],int l, int m);
```

instead of `int check(int arr[],int k);` and you should be fine. Based on how you change the `check()` function, change the way you invoke it inside the `for` loop in the `main()` function.

Comment: `int check(int arr[],int k);` is a pointer and an integer, it's exactly the same as `int check(int* arr,int k);`.